# Equivalent to `title(line = -1)` for `text()` in R graphics plotting

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I wish to position text in an R plot (using base graphics) so that the text appears exactly *x* lines above a given point.  This can be accomplished with `title(line = -x)`, but I'm not aware of an equivalent for `text()`.

The best hack I've come up with so far is to insert some newlines after the desired text:

```r
plot(0:2, 0:2, type = "n", ann = FALSE)
text(1, 1, "(1, 1)", col = 2)
text(1, 1, "Above (1, 1)\n\n", font = 2)
```

[image: Desired result]

However, this doesn't work for arbitrary non-integer *x*.

Bonus points for a solution that also allows text to be offset by an arbitrary number of em units (widths of an M, or equivalent) in the *x* direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the `legend()` source code led me to
`strheight("M")` (and `strwidth("M")`) to obtain the size of a plotted character.

```r
xOffset <- -1
yOffset <- 1
plot(0:2, 0:2, type = "n", ann = FALSE)
text(1, 1, "(1, 1)", col = 2)
text(x = 1 + (xOffset * strwidth("M")),
     y = 1 + (yOffset * strwidth("M") * par("lheight")),
     "Above (1, 1)",
     font = 2
)
```